# how close 2 pages in as.net and reflesh a grid

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I'm doing a job in asp.net:
I have 3 pages

1. pages have web service (grid)
2. import csv file data
3. I say how many lines imported into csv

the question is as follows:

When I click on the close button it closes (3 and 2) pages.
but the first one stays open and automatically reflesh the data on the grid.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Please read the [help] and take the [tour] to get some ideas on how to improve your question. It is best to include an example of what you have tired so far. Normally and asp.net application works in one browser window. How are these other windows opened?